# mpeg1 stream in online flash video player

Tags: flash, mp4, mpeg

I'm looking for a flash video player that can play mpeg1 streams (alternatively MP4 would work too). Are there any?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot play mpeg1 or mp4 directly in flash - you need to convert it to flv format.